# I have a Ender 3 S1 Pro and can't restart a print after a pause at height

Tags: creality-ender-3, marlin

My printer (Ender 3 S1 Pro) only has a touch screen. When I use the pause at height command, the print pauses properly. However, the screen only displays stop and pause "buttons". Neither of these options allows me to restart the print. Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I found that if I use Cura to generate the pause at height script then edit the G-code file and change the `M0` code to an `M25`. Next, you must use that edited file to print from an SD card. When the printer pauses and you are ready to continue the print (while connected to a computer with a USB cable and with Cura open), select the **Monitor** tab in Cura, type `M24` in the **Send** G-code window, and press the return key on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround I found is to insert custom G-code before the layer change and simply move the printer head out of the way, wait a couple of seconds so you can insert bearings, magnets, etc. then resumes the print.

```
M300 S440 P200        ;beep
G60                   ;save current position
G28  X0               ;home X axis, print head moves to the left
G4 S60                ;wait 60 seconds
M300 S440 P200        ;beep
G61                   ;restore saved position
```

Not as good as the printer prompting you but if you don't want to connect a computer then this is probably the simplest solution.